# Hexadecimal calculation for a checksum

Tags: math, hex

I'm not understanding how this result can be zero. This was presented to me has an example to validate a checksum of a message.

```
ED(12+01+ED=0)
```

How can this result be zero?

"1201 is the message" ED is the checksum, my question is more on, how can I determine the checksum?

Thank you for any help.

Best regards,
FR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ***How can this result be zero?***

The checksum is presumably represented by **a byte**.

A byte can store 256 different values, so the calculation is probably done **module 256**.

Since 0x12 + 0x01 + 0xED = 256, the result becomes 0.

> ***how can I determine the checksum?***

The checksum is the specific byte value `B` that makes the sum of the bytes in the message + `B` = 0 (modulo 256).

So, as @LanceH says in the comment, to figure out the checksum `B`, you...

1. add up the values of the bytes in the message (say it adds up to `M`)
2. compute `M' = M % 256`
3. Now, the checksum `B` is computed as `256 - M'`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit.  Add up the bytes of the message.  Take that sum modulo 256.  Subtract that number from 256 and that is your checksum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your checksum details but in base-16 arithmetic (and in base-10):

```
 base-16       base-10
-----------------------
   12            18
   01             1
+  ED           237
------------------------
  100           256
```

If your checksum is modulo-256 (16^2), you only keep the last 2 base-16 digits, so you have `00`

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, when you add up 12 + 01 + ED the result overflows 1 byte, and it's actually the hex number 100.  So, if you only take the final byte of 0x0100. you get 0.